# Cannot play video after downloading from server

Tags: android, media-player, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

my media recorder is recording  video after recording i am previewing my video (fine).
now uploaded this video on my local http server .
and finally getting this from server to play in a videoview but it shows cannot play video.

any suggestion where actually mistake is...
Thanx for help.

1. MediaRecorder

   ```
   this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
   this.mediaRecorder.setCamera(this.camera);
   camera.unlock();
   this.mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
   this.mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
   this.mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
   this.mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
   CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile_HQ = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P);
   this.mediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile_HQ);
   this.mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(this.initFile().getAbsolutePath());
    this.mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
    this.mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); 


    this.mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(this.cameraPreview.getHolder().getSurface());


     try {
       this.mediaRecorder.prepare();
       // start the actual recording
       // throws IllegalStateException if not prepared
       this.mediaRecorder.start();
       Toast.makeText(this, R.string.recording, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       // enable the stop button by indicating that we are recording
       this.toggleButtons(true);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.wtf(TAG, "Failed to prepare MediaRecorder", e);
       Toast.makeText(this, R.string.cannot_record, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       this.releaseMediaRecorder();
   }
   ```
2. Video view

   ```
      Uri uri = Uri.parse("/data/data/com.example.mediarecorder/files/"+  messageList.get(position)); //do not add any extension

               video.setVideoURI(uri);
               video.requestFocus(); 
               setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
               video.setKeepScreenOn(true);
               System.out.println(uri +  " "+ uri.getEncodedAuthority()+  " "+ uri.decode(data_type) + " "+ uri.getUserInfo() + " "+ uri.describeContents());
               video.start();
   ```

Answer (score 4):

You can't play video from internal storage via videoview, as the file does not have world readable permission. You have to create custom video player using surfaceView and media player class. Then you have to create a file descriptor of the file you need to play and pass that to mediaPlayer.setDataSource():

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(videoPath); 
//assume videoPath =   getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()) + File.separator + "Video.mp4" 
mp.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
        mp.prepareAsync();
        try {
            mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mplayer) {
                    if (mp != null) {
                        mp.start();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: actually i forgot to mention that i uploaded video to http server (filezila) and after that i am parsing the uri.
it is running on higher version of device like nexus 5 but not on other device such as karbon and galaxy tab. @Sunny